# What is div class="navigation" and why is it used?

Tags: html

What is `div class="navigation"` and why is it used?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include more details about the context in which this element is used. This question can't be answered like this.

Comment: You need to read a couple of HTML and CSS books or tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

1. Classes are used to define the behaviour of collection of HTML elements, similarly, ID's are used to define the behaviour of a single HTML element.
2. The class navigation has no special significance, and would initially be the same as a class called 'user' or 'glass' or 'cup'. Classes only become different to eachother once some styling or interactivity has been added to them using CSS or Javascript.

So in conclusion, the class 'navigation' doesn't mean anything apart from semantic meaning. For example, you might give a nav tag a class of 'navigation' for better understanding, but it wouldn't make a difference if that class was 'tree'.

Answer (score 1):

classes are used to make the html element Identifiable and make Styling using styling.css

hence ur not using any framework like bootstrap there is no significance for YOUR class name "navigation" "navigation" is just a class name

Comment: there is nothing to make it not to run!!for example in 
style.css 
.navigation{color:'red'}

it makes ur class text to red;

Answer (score 1):

The `class attribute` specifies one or more `classnames` for an element. The class attribute is mostly used to point to a class in a style sheet. However, it can also be used by a **JavaScript (via the HTML DOM)** to make changes to HTML elements with a specified class

The `.class selector` selects elements with a specific class attribute. To select elements with a specific class, write a `period (.) character`, followed by the name of the class. You can also specify that only specific HTML elements should be affected by a class.

so you can name the `class` according to your understanding .hope it would help you
for more information you can check it out this link

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp